# Restrict row matching between two arrays to values of specific columns

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to get the rows present in both arrays with a mask and locate them from the first.

I am able to do this and so far so good:

```
import numpy as np

array_1 = np.zeros((10,3), order = "F", dtype = int)

array_2 = np.zeros((5,3), order = "F", dtype = int)

array_1[:5][:,0] = 1
array_1[:5][:,1] = 1

array_2[:,0] = 1
array_2[:,1] = 1

m = (array_1[:, None] == array_2).all(-1).any(1)

print(array_1[m])
```

The issue is when I want to restrict the value comparison to only column 0 and column 1.

I have tried several ways, similar to this:

```
m = (array_1[:, None][:,0] == array_2[:,0]).all(-1).any(1)
```

Which returns an error like:

```
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all'
```

The goal is to get the entire rows but rather than check the values across all columns for a match, restrict to the columns that are only specified.

What would be the way to achieve the exact same thing but restrict it to comparing only the values of the first two columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it like this:

```
import numpy as np

array_1 = np.zeros((10,3), order = "F", dtype = int)

array_2 = np.zeros((5,3), order = "F", dtype = int)

array_1[:5][:,0] = 1
array_1[:5][:,1] = 1

array_2[:,0] = 1
array_2[:,1] = 1

m = (array_1[:,:2][:,None] == array_2[:,:2]).all(-1).any(1)

print(array_1[m])
```